# Creating a pre-recorded lecture

Tags: video, video-editing, screen-recording, presentation, powerpoint

I have created a PowerPoint presentation and I want to create a video of me presenting it. I'm looking for a software to make my life easier. The features I'm looking for are:

1. Can record a 25-minute video for free.
2. Works on Mac.
3. Can record the screen and me (audio+video).
4. Lets me rewind while recording and continue from there, so that if I make a tiny mistake I can just go a few seconds (or one slide) back and continue recording.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.